# HTML Table to render column wise

Tags: html, css

I have this basic table where i want to render row elements in such a way that it should render in vertical order. Each `<td>` inside `<tr>` should print in vertical order.

CSS and HTML :

```css
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table>tr>th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(odd)  {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr:first-child     {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}
```

```html
<table class="spec-table" id="here_table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan='4'>Single Mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>feature1</td>
    <td>feature2</td>
    <td>feature3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>value4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>test4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To fulfill this task, I just added two CSS property and its rendering as expected, but the table design scattered.

```css
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table>tr>th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(odd)  {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr:first-child     {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}

tr.orientation { display: inline-block;}
tr.orientation th, tr.orientation td { display:block;  }
```

```html
<table class="spec-table" id="here_table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan='4'>Single Mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>feature1</td>
    <td>feature2</td>
    <td>feature3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>value4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>test4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to fix the table design to look similar like before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table>tr>th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr td:nth-child(even) {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr td:nth-child(odd) {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr:first-child {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}

tr.orientation { display: table-cell;}
tr.orientation th, tr.orientation td {     
  display: grid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="spec-table" id="here_table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan='4'>Single Mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>feature1</td>
    <td>feature2</td>
    <td>feature3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>value4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="orientation">
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>test4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer but only works if the contents of the cells are the same height. If for example the "feature1" cell has multiple lines then the cells no longer align correctly. Not sure if there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table >tr >th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr:first-child {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}
```

```html
<table class="spec-table" id="here_table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan='4'>Single Mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>feature1</th>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>feature2</th>
    <td>value2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>feature3</th>
    <td>value3</td>
    <td>test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your css :

```
<style>
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table>tr>th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr td:nth-child(even) {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr td:nth-child(odd)  {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr:first-child     {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}

tr.orientation { display: inline-block;width: 33.3%;}
tr.orientation th, tr.orientation td { display:block;  }
td{border: 1px solid #fff;padding: 10px 67px;}
</style>
```

Comment: what if <tr> (rows) goes increase, this may print last rows in next line

Comment: you can set max-width for <tr>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```css
table{
  width:100%; 
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
table tr td, table tr th{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan="3">Single Mode</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>feature1</td>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>feature2</td>
      <td>value3</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>feature3</td>
      <td>value4</td>
      <td>test4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table.spec-table {border: 1px solid #fff; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 4em 0}
table.spec-table>tr>th {background-color: #333; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ddd}
table.spec-table tr:nth-child(odd)  {background: #eee}
table.spec-table tr:first-child     {background: #666; color: #fff; font-weight: bold}
table.spec-table th, td {font-size: .9em; padding: 7px; text-align: left;}

tr.orientation { display: inline-block;width:100%;}
tr.orientation th, tr.orientation td { display:block;width: 21%;float: left;}
```

```html
<table class="spec-table" id="here_table">
        <thead>
         <tr>
            <th colspan='4'>Single Mode</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="orientation">
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>feature1</td>
             <td>feature2</td>
             <td>feature3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="orientation">
             <td>value1</td>
             <td>value2</td>
             <td>value3</td>
             <td>value4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="orientation">
             <td>test1</td>
             <td>test2</td>
             <td>test3</td>
             <td>test4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: The table is not rendering column wise.